# MongoDB hidden secondary stuck in startup?

Tags: mongodb

I am creating a hidden secondary MongoDB instance that will eventually be used for reporting.  So far I have taken these steps:

1. Started up my primary instance (local machine) with `replSet = mySet` and called `rs.initiate()`
2. Started up my secondary instance with with `replSet = mySet`
3. Called `rs.add("my.secondary.com")` from my primary instance
4. set `priority = 0` and `hidden = true` for the secondary member using `rs.reconfigure(cfg)`

When I do this and call `rs.status()` I get the following output:

```
{
  "set": "mySet",
  "date": ISODate("2016-03-22T16:40:39.515Z"),
  "myState": 1,
  "members": [
    {
      "_id": 0,
      "name": "my-machine.local:27017",
      "health": 1,
      "state": 1,
      "stateStr": "PRIMARY",
      "uptime": 607,
      "optime": Timestamp(1458664559, 1),
      "optimeDate": ISODate("2016-03-22T16:35:59Z"),
      "electionTime": Timestamp(1458664264, 2),
      "electionDate": ISODate("2016-03-22T16:31:04Z"),
      "configVersion": 3,
      "self": true
    },
    {
      "_id": 1,
      "name": "my.secondary.com:27017",
      "health": 1,
      "state": 0,
      "stateStr": "STARTUP",
      "uptime": 384,
      "optime": Timestamp(0, 0),
      "optimeDate": ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
      "lastHeartbeat": ISODate("2016-03-22T16:40:38.332Z"),
      "lastHeartbeatRecv": ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
      "pingMs": 106,
      "configVersion": -2
    }
  ],
  "ok": 1
}
```

Notice that `stateStr` for my secondary is `STARTUP` - this never changes and the data never replicates.  In a previous attempt I also called `rs.iniate()` on my secondary, but that made what was intended to be the secondary become the primary.  I had to blow everything away and start again.

Why is my secondary stuck in `STARTUP` and how can I get my data to begin replicating from my primary to my secondary?

Comment: Give it some time. It may be syncing with primary so will take sometime depending on how large your data is. Also please make sure if both primary and secondary nodes are accessible to each other and no firewall is interfering.

Comment: I'm not sure - according to the link below the state would be `STARTUP2` if it were synching: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/replica-states/

Comment: Also - I'm not sure about the secondary having access to the primary since the Primary is my local machine.  I thought the communication was just one way - Primary -> Secondary.  Is that not the case?

Comment: Both do ping each other (heart-beat).

Comment: Please see my post below. these work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is checklist from my black book:) compare your steps, it should go without a glitch.

(assuming you initiated mongodb instances with --replSet flag)

```
// rs.initiate()
// rs.add("host-1:29001")
// rs.add("host-2:30001")
// rs.add("host-n:40001")
// var cfg = rs.config()
// cfg.members[2].priority = 0
// cfg.members[2].hidden = true
// rs.reconfig(cfg)
```

Comment: yeah these are my steps.  I'm not sure my secondary can access my Primary so that may be the issue.  I will look into that

Comment: Try initiating replica on your local machine first before spending time with live environment. This will give you confidence in what are you doing. (at least setting up replicaSet for MongoDB)

Comment: yeah working on setting up my secondary locally right now - I think that's a good step

Comment: I think it was just the two way communication thing.  Once I set things up locally it worked